# Implementing strftime and strptime for custom date class

Tags: python, strptime, strftime

I've written a custom date class for a non-Gregorian calendar system.

Is there an easy way to implement `strftime` and `strptime` without having to implement all the logic myself?

My class has a day, month and year field, so in principle all I would need to provide the existing `strftime` and `strptime` implementations are the names of months and days of the week as strings.

Comment: Well, `strftime` just delegates to the C library function, so it might be impossible

Comment: Both `strftime` and `strptime` have a [format option](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes). Is this not sufficient? If so, please describe your requirements in more detail.